# Durandal in chrome addin

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, mvvm, add-in, durandal

I want to develop a google chrome addin. For MVVM composition I would like to use DurandalJS. As I am new to chrome addin development I would like to know wether this is possible or if chrome's sandboxing mechanism would block Durandal or one of it's sub-APIs like sammyJS or requireJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without trying this specific case, it should just work like in any other webpage.

From the Chrome developer website:

> If you want to use a library that the browser doesn't provide (for
>   example, jQuery), you can bundle that library's JavaScript files with
>   your extension. **Bundled libraries work in extensions just as they do
>   in other web pages**.

(emphasis mine)

**Source**: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_other.html

If anything, you can do more in a chrome addon than on a regular website. If not, what would be the use of an addon if you could just use a bookmark instead?

Comment: Thanks for the info. However, for the website issue: For some smaller tasks which are used quite frequently designing addins is a better approach. In my case creating a website would be an overkill. ^^